# dpkg: error processing archive

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, deb

I get the following error when running the command:

```
   $ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get autoclean -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y
    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                          
    Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                   
    Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                             
    Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                           
    Hit:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                           
    Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
    Hit:8 https://packages.cisofy.com/community/lynis/deb xenial InRelease
    Hit:9 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease
    Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
    Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
    Reading package lists... Done                      
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages have been kept back:
      libmm-glib0 libqmi-proxy modemmanager
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      avahi-dnsconfd
    1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
    Need to get 14.1 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 avahi-dnsconfd amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1 [14.1 kB]
    Fetched 14.1 kB in 0s (168 kB/s)          
    dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'avahi-daemon' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
    (Reading database ... 280768 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
    Job for avahi-daemon.socket canceled.
    dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
    Job for avahi-daemon.socket canceled.
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/avahi-daemon.*
```

But it didn't help.

Information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mybox 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: do `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/avahi-dnsconfd_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` and  `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro those commands execute successfully but I still get the original error when running the original command.

Comment: I think you are getting them now because you deleted the scripts from "/var/lib/dpkg/info/".  One of the solutions might be extracting manually them from the .deb file, and putting them there. There are other not-so-elegant solutions, I would prefer to wait and see if someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768949

I was able to fix my broken upgrade by doing

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon
```